# How do I manipulate WebGrids?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I'm using ASP.NET and the MVC pattern.
I have the following code which I use to style the columns:

```
<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Amount", "Amount", canSort: true, style: "column"),
            grid.Column("ShelfLife", "ShelfLife", canSort: true, style: "column"),
            grid.Column("Size", "Size", canSort: true, style: "column"),
            grid.Column("Type", "Type", canSort: true, style: "column"),
            grid.Column("Unit", "Unit", canSort: true, style: "column")
    ))
</div>
```

I use the following code to load the data for the grid:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "null");
}
```

It's probably a long and trivial way of doing this... but I'd like to know how I can manipulate what's in the grid? For example, I'd like to add a button for every row. I'd also like to recolour every second row. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use styles for changing the color of rows in grid and check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/875859/Insert-Update-and-Delete-MVC-WebGrid-Data-using-JQ) for manipulating the grid.

You can define custom css class in a separate css file

```
.comments {
    width: 500px;
}
```

and then assign this class to the corresponding  elements:

```
webGrid.Column(columnName: "TRP_Comments", header: "Comments", style: "comments")
```

Comment: Do you know how to set the width or the just set the style of all the columns? I'm following his example where he creates the columns through c# code.